# What is the difference between setExact, setInexactRepeating and setRepeating? when and which to use?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

Hi I am using `alarmManager` to trigger alarm for every 3 minutes. So I used `setRepeating` method for alarm to trigger for every 3 minutes. This works in some device. But when it goes in sleep mode and then turned on, alarm is not working.

```
  public void startAt3() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    /* Set the alarm */
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    /* Repeating on every 3 minute interval */
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 3, pendingIntent);
}
```

I read that it goes to doze mode in android 6.0. So which is appropriate to use instead of `setRepeating` method?

Answer (score 0):

**setExact** - This is used to set an alarm to be delivered precisely at the stated time.

**setInexactRepeating** - This is used to set some predefined time interval for the alarm. Is this better than `setRepeating()`? This approach consumes less resource, less battery in comparison with the other. So it is recommended to use `setInexactRepeating()` whenever possible. Android will synchronize multiple in-exact alarms at run time to save resources. Below are the possible values for in-exact repeating; (prior to api level 19)

```
INTERVAL_DAY

INTERVAL_HALF_DAY

INTERVAL_HOUR

INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR

INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES
```

**setRepeating** - This is used to set exact time for the alarm down to milliseconds. Do we really have to use this? Since this method is more resource consuming, Nobody recommend this approach unless it is really necessary.